# Import errors on subsystems for ZODB, but only for Py.Test

Tags: python, pytest, importerror, zodb

Running `PyTest` with files including `ZODB` gives an odd problem: `ZODB` can be imported, but its component FileSystem cannot.

```
import ZODB   # That works fine.
import ZODB.FileStorage
ImportError: No module named FileStorage
```

On the other hand, running the same code from the Python interpreter runs fine.

This is version `PyTest version 3.2.2, Python 2.7.13, and ZODB 5.2.4`
There exists `ZODB-5.2.4-py2.7.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/init.py, a ZODB.pth` pointing to the egg, and no other modules have issues; just any submodule of `ZODB`. No odd permission errors. After an hour of experiments and exercising Google-Fu, I got nothing.

### Any workaround would be appreciated.

Well, I dropped this because it 'went away'.  Now its back.  This I know so far:

- This shows up sometimes with PyTest, usually running a profiler.  I haven't found a way around it.  I don't
  know what causes it.  I have some issues filed but haven't tracked it down.

  ```
  File "/Users/cmerriam/p/platform/zzz/data/ZODB.py", line 41, in <module>
  import ZODB.FileStorage                                 # flake8: noqa
  ImportError: No module named FileStorage
  ```

#### Things I see:

```
  * Same issue from PyCharm or command line.
  * No issue running normal code from PyCharm or command line.
  * Once it starts to be an issue, it continues.  Still don't know why.
  * Once it goes away it stays away.
  * My edit configuration has a warning "No Py.Test runner found for current configuration", though 
  /opt/zzz/bin/py.test is in path
  * Seems to have occurred after a reboot.
  * No reason, at all, to suspect FileStorage.
  * This is in my ...../site-packages directory:


        $ ls -l ZODB*
        -rw-rw-r--  1 cmerriam  zzz  23 Oct  6 18:08 ZODB.pth

        ZODB-5.2.4-py2.7.egg:
        total 0
        drwxr-xr-x   9 cmerriam  zzz   306 Oct  6 18:08 EGG-INFO/
        drwxr-xr-x  74 cmerriam  zzz  2516 Oct  9 15:58 ZODB/


        $ cd ZODB-5.2.4-py2.7.egg
        $ tree
           |-EGG-INFO
           |-ZODB
           |---FileStorage
           |---__pycache__
           |---scripts
           |-----manual_tests
           |-----tests
           |---tests
```

#### Things that haven't worked:

- Uninstall and reinstall PyTest
- Restart pycharm checking environment
- Right-click in project "clean compiled python files"
- Running regular python test first.
- Running pytest from command line in different directories
- Reboot again
- Pip Install pytest-runner
- Install new zzz version
- Run 'python setup.py install'
- Moving ZODB-5.2.4-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/ to ZODB-5.2.4-py2.7.egg-info

## Aha!   A CLUE!

There exists in the system a module named zzz.data.zodb.py.  And I'm working on OS/X which is case preserving but not case sensitive.  And yet I got a point with both "zzz.data.zodb" and "zzz.data.ZODB" in my sys.modules.  And can we just make it an error to have two items align but for case yet?

I still would like nail down the edge cases of what happened.

Comment: have you tried absolute import?

Comment: Well, I just renamed the offending module.  I haven't been able to pare down a test case that correctly fails in PyTest.

Comment: Maybe module with same name located in sys.path. Try to see which files module uses import ZODB; print(ZODB.__file__)

Comment: It sounds like exactly what it's telling you: there's no module named FileStorage.  This has happened to me before when I was using an outdated version of the package which had a different name, have you verified that the ZODB package you've got is the one you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
from ZODB import FileStorage
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Something Like the following as discribed in another answer:

> @A. Dickey -
>
> from ZODB import FileStorage

In the comments discribes:

> @nes -
> Maybe module with same name located in sys.path. Try to see which files module uses `import ZODB; print(ZODB.__file__)`